# Why does Mojolicious nest my routes?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

My Mojolicious application has some custom authentication mechanism, which I implement in a routing condition called `auth_permission`:

```
$app->add_condition(auth_permission => sub {
    return is_user_allowed(...) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

So my routes look something like this:

```
my $r = $app->routes;

$r->get('/prefs')
    # no permission necessary here
  ->to(...);

$r->get('/objects')
  ->over(auth_permission => 'view objects')
  ->to(...);

$r->get('/objects/delete/:id')
  ->over(auth_permission => 'delete objects')
  ->to(...);
```

The `to()` clauses are handled correctly: `GET /objects` gives me the object list, and `GET /objects/delete/42` deletes object 42.

The problem is that the permission `view objects` is checked for both requests, even though the second route should check the permission `delete objects`.

The reason seems to be that `/objects/delete/42` is a path below `/objects`. The same problem does not occur with the route `/prefs`, which does not have a common base with the other routes.

My current workaround is to place the rule for `/objects` *below* the one for `/objects/delete/:id`, but that's a) unelegant and is b) going to break when another developer edits the file. Can I explicitly disable the nesting behavior seen in this case?

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward behaviour to me. And your so called workaround is a logical consequence of how Mojolicious matches routes. IMO you answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mojolicious docs seem to indicate that you should be building the extended route off the object that handles the shorter one. See the [Nested Routes](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Nested_routes) Section of the docs.

This means you have a $objects route, and a $objects_delete route derived from it. Eliminates ordering problems (other than having to declare the shorter route first).